# VB6 copy long string to text box

Tags: string, vb6

Hi Apologize if this question doesn't form well with stack overflow. 
However, I am trying to assign a VERY long string to a text box programmatically but only part of my string is coming in. The rest is cut off.

```
  Text1.Text = UPCSTRING
```

UPCSTRING is about 319,000 chars and has line breaks after each 70 chars. 
Why doesn't the whole string show up in the textbox? 
IS there a better way to do this?

PS if I debug.print UPCSTRING my whole string shows up.

Comment: you understand, that a 3 mb size string is a little to much input for a UI textbox? it is really unrealistic to enter that size into a textbox. what exact are you trying? and did you set the text box properties to accept that length (although I´m pretty sure storing 3mb in a textbox in nonsense, and the max textbox size is around 64K)

Comment: why do you think a string with 319,000 characters is 3MB?  --- argh I typo'd one to many zero in my above statement

Comment: still the limit is 64 KB (for textbox)

Comment: How much of the string is actually displayed in the textbox?

Comment: Well it's a little weird because I am having users paste in data into Text1 box. (pasting 11 digit strings, 1 per row) Each 11 digit string per row. They paste in 29,000 rows (each with 11 digit strings). The routine, cleans up the 29,000 rows. Replaces all line breaks with "," commas and then assigns the whole string to a variable. WORKS... Then it tries to replace Text in Text1 box with the value of the cleaned up string and only a small part goes back into the box. Approx 5000 rows worth (of course with rows removed). IF it held that much text to begin with... why can't same amount go back?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [MSDN Article on the VB6 Textbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733608(v=vs.60).aspx), there are limitations to the amount of text it will hold:

> By default, you can enter up to 2048 characters in a text box. If you
>   set the MultiLine property of the control to True, you can enter up to
>   32K of text.

As others have commented, anything that large is just nonsense to the user.

If you insist on this interface, perhaps switching to the [Rich Text Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261653(v=vs.60).aspx) will help as it doesn't have the text limitation that the standard Text Box does.

Comment: Well it's a little weird because I am having users paste in data into Text1 box. (pasting 11 digit strings, 1 per row) Each 11 digit string per row. They paste in 29,000 rows (each with 11 digit strings). The routine, cleans up the 29,000 rows. Replaces all line breaks with "," commas and then assigns the whole string to a variable. WORKS... Then it tries to replace Text in Text1 box with the value of the cleaned up string and only a small part goes back into the box. Approx 5000 rows worth (of course with rows removed). IF it held that much text to begin with... why can't same amount go back?

Comment: "They paste in 29,000 rows..." Is this some kind of special torture?  I'm not sure what kind of answer you want about why something works the way it does in VB6. Microsoft dropped support for the IDE over 9 years ago. They probably aren't going to fix it. If you are looking for a way to give the 'cleansed' data back to the user, rather than using the text box, how about Clipboard.SetText ? Or throw the data into a file.

Comment: I am just pointing out that if the data fits in the textbox in the first place it's probably not a textbox limitation. Something else is wrong. Aside from rebuilding the whole thing with .net might you have an idea of what is going on here or how to fix it?

Comment: Best option is a third party textbox control or the rich text box control.

Answer (score 0):

A normal text box cannot accommodate maximum 255 char length.
Set Text1.Multiline = true above 255 character length. Even Multiline text box restricted to  32,000. In that case go for  Rich text box.

Comment: I already have multi line text box enabled. Please read my other commentary.

Comment: it's not a limit of the textbox itself something else is wrong.