# visual basic 6 load html file into text1: not loading all of the content

Tags: vb6

here is my code , am trying to load html file from app.path how ever it is not populating all the data only half of it,  am not sure why.

i expected the data to be populated till the end of the file.

```
Public Function ReadTextFileIntoString(strPathToFile As String) As String
  Dim objFSO As New FileSystemObject
  Dim objTxtStream As TextStream
  Dim strOutput As String
  Set objTxtStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strPathToFile)
  Do Until objTxtStream.AtEndOfStream
   strOutput = strOutput + objTxtStream.ReadLine
  Loop

  objTxtStream.Close
  Text1.text = Text1.text & strOutput
End Function



Private Sub Command8_Click()
'Open App.Path & "\" & "File.html" For Input As #1
ReadTextFileIntoString App.Path & "\" & "File.html"

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you have exceeded the text control max length?

Comment: Here is a link discussing this issue:  [VB6 copy long string to text box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42539258/5162073)